# To find the maximum value within the matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, max

i have a matrix data. How can i find the maximum value in the given matrix.

```
 > data
         [,1]  
   [1,] "1714.12"  
   [2,] Character,2

 > data[2,1]
   [1] "14777.15" "1421.45"
 > class(data)
   [1] "matrix"
```

How can i find the maximum value in the above matrix `data`, Whish is 14777.15 ??

**The data:**

```
data <- structure(list("1714.12", c("14777.15", "1421.45")), .Dim = c(2L, 1L))
```

Comment: There is no numeric data in your matrix. Only characters.

Comment: Please show us `dput(data)`

Comment: You should be able to use `max(as.numeric(c(data)))`

Comment: `dput(data)`
 `structure(list("1714.12", c("14777.15", "1421.45")), .Dim = c(2L, 
1L))`
@RichardScriven

Comment: @RichardScriven
`>max(as.numeric(c(data)))`
`Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data <- structure(list("1714.12", c("14777.15", "1421.45")), .Dim = c(2L, 1L))
```

In a "standard" R matrix, `c(data)` will return the entire matrix in atomic vector form.  But if we look at `c(data)` here, we see that it's actually a list.

```
c(data)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1714.12"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "14777.15" "1421.45"
```

You can use `max()` after `unlist()`.  But you'll need to use `as.numeric()` because you have character values there.

```
max(as.numeric(unlist(data)))
# [1] 14777.15
```

Note:  It might be a good idea to backtrack and find where the numerics are made into character and adjust it accordingly so you don't run into other issues.